# Finding items through array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find the results for a huge array (7000+ items) and for some reason, the script I used before for another project keeps returning false, or I'm probably forgetting something.

I am trying to sort through an array and find two items that's listed in a variable. Here's the code:

```
$.getJSON('proxy.php?url=http://api.bukget.org/api/plugins', function(data){
        var list = ['essentials', 'worldguard'];
        //console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function(i, plugin){
            if (plugin === list) {
                console.log('found!');
                 } else {
                    return false;
                }
        });

    });
```

What am I missing from my code?

Using A Proxy:

```
<?php

    if (!isset($_GET['url'])) die();
    $url =  urldecode($_GET['url']);
    $url = 'http://' . str_replace('http://', '', $url); // Avoid accessing the file system
    echo file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

Which makes the data (snippet):

```
["a5h73y", "ab-marriage", "abacus", "abag", "abandonedcarts", "abilitytrader", "abitofrealism", "aboot", "absorbchests", "acc", "acceptdarules", "acceptrules", "accesscontrol", "accessories", "accident-tnt", "accountlock", "achat", "achievement", "achievements", "acientcave", "acommands", "actionzones", "activator", "activityhistory", "activitypromotion", "activitytracker"]
```

Comment: remove the whole `else` block.

Comment: Could you post the structure of `data`? It seems to be an object as you're using `$.getJSON` but you said it was an array so it's a bit confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`return false` will break out of the `$.each` if `plugin !== list` in the first iteration.

**Edit:** If you want to find for any of items inside `list` and stop matching it'd be:

```
$.getJSON('proxy.php?url=http://api.bukget.org/api/plugins', function(data) {
    var list = ['essentials', 'worldguard'],
        found;
    $.each(data, function(i, plugin) {
        if (~$.inArray(plugin, list)) {
            found = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    if (found) {
        console.log('found!');
    } else {
        console.log('not found!');
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r5QbE/)

If you want to find both of them:

```
$.getJSON('proxy.php?url=http://api.bukget.org/api/plugins', function(data) {
    var list = ['essentials', 'worldguard'],
        found = 0;
    $.each(data, function(i, plugin) {
        if (~$.inArray(plugin, list)) {
            found++;
        }
    });
    if (found === list.length) {
        console.log('found all of them!');
    } else {
        console.log(found + ' items found.');
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r5QbE/2/)

Comment: I am using your exact script (copy pasta) and it returns not found!.

Comment: The `data` you pasted is from inside the `$.getJSON`? From your console.log(data) check if the items you're looking for are actually there.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answer, array literals can't reliably be compared with `==`. Use `.indexOf`:

```
if ( list.indexOf(plugin) > -1 ) {

}
```

Comment: `plugin` is a property value of a JSON object. How do you apply this to OP's case?

Comment: He was right. It was a string. Fab's and yours was correct, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Is `plugin` an array or a string? If it's an array, array comparison is not available in Javascript (example: http://jsfiddle.net/F36Qd/)

If `plugin` is a string, here is the way to know if it's in `list`:

```
if (list.indexOf(plugin) > -1 ) {
    // Found
}
```

If `plugin` is an array you'll have to write a function that makes deep object comparison.